# Submit text field using watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I am trying to programmatically submit text into a text field using watir. I'm using Stack Overflow as a test site for the script.

I was able to reference the search field (`name='q'`) but the submit button doesn't have an `id` or `name` attribute. So how do you reference the submit button programmatically and click it?

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```
require 'watir'
require 'pry'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true

browser.goto 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'
browser.text_field(:name, "q").set('user:963076') #the search bar name='q'
browser.button(#how do I reference the submit button?, '').click
browser.screenshot.save 'screenafter.png' #the screenshot is so that I know what happened after clicking

browser.close
browser.quit
```

A direct answer to the question is good, but an explanation about how to find solutions to problems like this on your own is better and very much appreciated.

Comment: I just updated the Watir website with a Guide on how to use Watir locators: http://watir.com/guides/locating/ Also, we recommend using a Hash as the selector now instead of an ordered pair of parameters (how, what), since multiple locators can be combined as necessary.

Comment: @titusfortner Hi It's an excellent read, and this page `http://xpathify.herokuapp.com/` is awesome! Thanks for mentioning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to click this button

```
<button type="submit" aria-label="Search..." class="s-btn s-btn__primary btn-topbar-primary js-search-submit"><svg aria-hidden="true" class="svg-icon mx0 iconSearch" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18"><path d="M12.86 11.32L18 16.5 16.5 18l-5.18-5.14v-.35a7 7 0 1 1 1.19-1.19h.35zM7 12A5 5 0 1 0 7 2a5 5 0 0 0 0 10z"></path></svg></button>
```

The button has the type attribute with the value of `submit` so we can use that to locate that button, here is the code

```
browser.goto 'https://www.stackoverflow.com'
browser.text_field(name: "q").set('user:963076')
browser.button(type: 'submit').click
```